# Request to get user info from Spotify Web API results in 401 error

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, axios, spotify, hapi.js

I want to use the Spotify API to retrieve a user's info. I've already figured out to get an `access token`. First I get the authorization code from Spotify and I send that to and endpoint that generates an `access token`, this looks as so...

```
const access = async (req, h) => {

// URL to retrieve an access token.
const spotify_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";

// Send authorization code to spotify.
const response = await axios({
  method: "post",
  url: spotify_url,
  params: {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: req.query.auth_code,
    redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI
  },
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + (Buffer.from(process.env.CLIENT_ID + ":" + process.env.CLIENT_SECRET).toString("base64"))
  }
})
.then(response => {

  // Retrieve access and refresh tokens.
  let access_token = response.data.access_token;
  let response_token = response.data.refresh_token

  return {
    access_token: access_token,
    response_token: response_token
  }

})
...
...
return result
```

I didn't add all the code but it works perfectly. What is being returned is the `access token` and the `refresh token`.

I am using `Hapi.js` so I am putting this in a `pre` handler and sending the `access token` to another handler/function which then uses the `access token` to retrieve the user's information...

```
const user_account = async (access_token) => {

  const user = await axios.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", {
    header: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    }
  })
  .then(response => {

    // Return the full details of the user.
    return response;

  })
  .catch(err => {
    throw Boom.badRequest(err);
  });

  return user;
}
```

The problem is that I am getting an `401` error.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 401

It seems that my `access token` might not be valid. That's the only thing I can think of, however, I checked and I am sending the same token that was generated by the first function, so it should be valid. Maybe the way I'm formatting my request is wrong. I can't figure out what the reason for this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have small typo error in axios.get request. Change header to headers

Change

```
 header: {
  "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
}
```

To

```
 headers: {
  "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
}
```

Comment: Jeez, this problem really didn't deserve the amount of time I spent on it. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed, we all do such silly mistakes :) It happens sometimes. Cheers